# Potential downsides to getting a Polish passport?

Tags: eu-citizens, polish-citizens

Due to recent "Reasons" my UK passport is not as useful as it once was for traveling, living and working in the EU. However my grandfather is Polish. Which means I am able to get a Polish passport (Citizenship).

I want to do a quick check to see if there would be any downsides to this. (I will do a proper due diligence closer to the time)

I am particularly concerned if there my be National Service or Tax implications. Not just for myself but also for any children I may have. (I/They are/would be currently UK/NZ citizens and NZ tax residents)

So my question is:

**Are there any significant downsides to getting a Polish passport, as a citizen of a different country?**

Answer (score 4):

Poland taxes based on residency, not citizenship.
Therefore, being a Polish citizen should not make any difference on your general taxation status so long as you don't live in Poland.

However, tax is a complicated subject and is subject to double taxation agreements between countries.  As such, then that agreements between Poland and UK might be different to that between Poland and New Zealand (or any other country).  So you would have to engage tax advisors with suitable experience in each double taxation agreement to be sure that you wouldn't be taxable in specific circumstances, for example if you own property in Poland and how that might be taxed by each country.

Poland no longer has national service, so this should not be an issue.  I do believe that they reserve the right to call up their citizens in an Emergency, although if you live abroad and don't speak the language at all or well then you would not be top of the list to be conscripted.

As for your children.  Just because you might be Polish does not mean that they automatically gain this citizenship.  Although, they might well qualify through their great-grandparents they would have to apply separately and be assessed individually.